# Polycom Microbrowser show return on text input

Tags: php, html

I am programming on PHP and HTML for the Polycom Phones microbrowser. I would like to know if is it possible to change the SoftKeys indexes for the Edit Active mode of the microbrowser (when the focus is in the textbox) I also would like to know if is it possible to set up a numeric input, or change the input for numbers as default on a text input.